# Brackets added to Scanned Codes

Tags: barcode-scanner

When my barcode scanner scans a code, it adds ] to the beggining and [ to the end. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a barcode scanner setup parameter and varies by the particular barcode reader.  You will need the documentation / SDK for your barcode scanner.  Many barcode scanners can setup the leading/trailing character just by scanning a setup barcode.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the documents and set up to have no leading characters, and the trailing character as a carriage return, but the brackets still show. The person I bought it from had mentioned that I would have to change the regional settings, but I can't figure out what to do. I've contacted him about this, but have yet to recieve a response. This is the item: [link](http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&_trksid=p4340.l2557&rt=nc&nma=true&item=370496284752&si=jFICt6l0DRzGEDVhGLltUAYHqGM%253D&viewitem=&sspagename=STRK%3AMEWAX%3AIT#ht_4822wt_1139)